# Solidity - Calling parent payable not possible?

Tags: solidity, payable, inheritance

I'm trying to inherit and override a parent's payable function (and adding some modifier and logic) but so far seem unable to do so.

My first intuitive try was something like this:

```
contract foo {
    function test() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return msg.value;
    }
}

contract bar is foo {
    function test() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return super.test.value(msg.value / 2)();
    }
}
```

and received compile error:

```
TypeError: Member "value" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function () - did you forget the "payable" modifier?
    super.test.value(msg.value)();
```

Give the function a different name doesn't work either so it's not an overriding issue.

```
contract foo {
    function test() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return msg.value;
    }
}

contract bar is foo {
    function anotherTest() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return super.test.value(msg.value / 2)();
    }
}
```

I got slightly further by tricking compiler with a casting but this is obviously no good as would cause infinite loop at runtime:

```
contract foo {
    function test() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return msg.value;
    }
}

contract bar is foo {
    function test() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return foo(address(this)).test.value(msg.value / 2)();
    }
}
```

What works is combining the two, i.e. giving it a different name and casting:

```
contract foo {
    function test() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return msg.value;
    }
}

contract bar is foo {
    function anotherTest() public payable returns (uint256) {
        return foo(address(this)).test.value(msg.value / 2)();
    }
}
```

Now calling bar.test() with 6 wei returns 6 and calling bar.anotherTest() returns 3. But this isn't exactly what I want as it still exposes test() through bar.

So what am I doing wrong, or is this by design? Would really like to understand why Solidity behave this way and if there's a workaround to achieve what I want. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `foo` is the base contract of `bar` when you call `super.test()` you are calling yourself within the same contract.

Now your are trying to send yourself half of `msg.value` and the other half will still be in your contract.

I'd recommend to pass the desired value as parameter of the function.

Comment: Yeah, I eventually figured it out. As you explained, I'm calling within the same contract and there's really no reason to resend ether to the same pocket, simply calling `super.test()` without `.value` or with a parameter would do. Thanks!